# Obtener el id de una table HTML, utilizando un bucle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

Tengo un div, en el cual voy a crear un número indeterminados de tablas el cual tendrá un id no númerico, una vez ya creadas esas tablas me gustaría recorrerlas una a una y obtener su id ya que lo utilizaré para posteriores procesos.

Existe alguna forma de obtener el id de la tabla, ya sea por JavaScript o utilizando la librería JQuery? 
Este es parte de mi script:

```
<script>
        var div = document.getElementById('divTablas'); //un div que contiene un número  n de tablas

        for (var i = 1; i <= div.getElementsByTagName('table').length; i++) {

         var idTabla = //como obtengo el id de la tabla que está recorriendo mi bucle?
        }
</script>
```

O hay alguna forma de obtener un array con las id de las tablas que hay en mi DIV, para despues recorrer el array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes preguntar en `jQuery` por el atributo `id`. Es muy fácil de recorrer con each a partir de un selector como por ejemplo una clase común.

```
$(".clase").each(function (){
    $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tenía la idea pero no sabía como utilizarlo, muchas gracias. al final quedó así:     $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".divTablasClass").each(function () {
                    alert($(this).attr('id'));
                });
            });

Comment: Nada, para eso estamos :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener todas las clases con `querySelectorAll` y lo recorres con un `for`

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".clase");
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  let id = divs[i].id;
  console.log("resultado :", id);
}
```

```html
<div id="uno" class="clase">hola 1</div>
<div id="dos" class="clase">hola 2</div>
<div id="tres" class="clase">hola 3</div>
<div id="cuatro" class="clase">hola 4</div>
<div id="cinco" class="clase">hola 5</div>
```